# VS Code (Flutter, dart) error don't go away after commenting or deleting code

Tags: visual-studio, android-studio, flutter, dart

I'm using Mac OS Catalina (10.15.3) Here is my code.

[image: error]

`dart` shows an error `Only static members can be accessed in initializers`

And that's it. Error doesn't go away. Even when comment everything delete everything dart continues giving that error. I don't understand. Was working in `Android Studio`. Exactly the same. I thought it was `Android Studio` problem. Because of that I downloaded `VS Code` but again. Here is the photo of error after I comment lines.

[image]

Please help me. It annoys me. I don't know what to do.

Edit 1:
I could reproduce the issue.
Let's say I have some `StateLessWidget` class

```
class SearchPage extends StatelessWidget {
    // Whenever I try to write property beginning with type Future
    Future<... // <--- Android Studio and VS Code both stop working.
               // then it starts working when I restart

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container();
    }
}
```

Then doesn't matter what you do. Nothing works until restart.

Comment: did u close vscode and open it again? What does flutter doctor give you?

Comment: @PeterHaddad yes. Look like VS Code crashed. It freeze a little. Couldn't save file. No autocomplete nothing. Then after 10 mins opened in Android Studio works fine. Very weird. Flutter doctor - No issues found!

Comment: Huh... Strange. I've had an issue like this once or twice, whenever my PC gets slow, but it worked after a simple restart... Did ya install any new extension or something that may be affecting vscode? I gotta say, there's a lotta nifty features in vscode that I don't think are available in android studio

Comment: In your screenshots, the analyzer is still running (bottom left). Do you still have this error after it finishes ?

Comment: @MickaelHrndz it does not finish. I tried waiting an hour. I could reproduce the issue.

Comment: @MickaelHrndz  please look at my edit

Comment: @PeterHaddad Please look at my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a few things you can try :

- Update VS Code.
- Does `flutter doctor -v` contains any error message ?
- Try running `flutter clean`
- Open pubspec.yaml, right-click and "Get Packages".
- Move to another channel (`flutter channel beta` for example) and run
  `flutter upgrade`
- Delete and reinstall Flutter and its IDE extensions